# In linear algebra, why is the dual basis of a basis the *rows* of the matrix $A^{-1}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis, dual-spaces

When finding the dual basis, we first find the transition matrix from the basis to the other (dual) basis. So if I have some basis in $\mathbf{R^2}$ $\{(a, b), (c, d)\}$, and I want to find the dual basis in terms of the standard basis, the transition matrix would be

$A =\begin{bmatrix}
    a & c \\
    b & d
\end{bmatrix}$

Lastly, we find $A^{-1}$. This gives us the dual basis vectors as the rows.

$1.$ Is my understanding up to this point correct?

$2.$ In linear algebra, why is the dual basis of a basis the *rows* of the matrix $A^{-1}$? After all, it's the columns that are the vectors.

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this.

Comment: Very late to the party comment: since you seem to mean dual relative to the dot product, it's immediate from the facts that (i) $A^{-1}A=I$ and (ii) the entries of that product are the rows of $A^{-1}$ dotted with the columns of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

This works for every ${\Bbb R}^n$ and in fact for every finite dimensional vector space $V$ over any field $K$.

To fix ideas, consider ${\Bbb R}^n$ with its standard basis $\{e_i\}$, and the dual $({\Bbb R}^n)^\ast$ with the dual basis $\{e_i^\ast\}$.

Given a basis $\{v_i\}$, let $A=(a_{ij})$ be the matrix whose $j$-th column is the components of $v_j$ in terms of the standard basis.

Expressing the dual basis $\{v_i^\ast\}$ in terms of the standard dual basis amounts to finding expressions
$$
v_i^\ast=\sum_{j=0}^nb_{ij}e_j^\ast.
$$
But just because $v_i^\ast(v_j)=\delta_i^j$these coefficients $b_{ij}$ must satisfy the relations
$$
\sum_{\ell=1}^nb_{i\ell}a_{\ell j}=\delta_i^j,
$$
which makes clear that they are indeed the *rows* of the inverse matrix $A^{-1}$ because the rows of that matrix satisfy that property.

Answer (score 0):

I try to share my ideas though I'm not sure if I had correctly understand your question XD.

If I write your $A$ as 
$A =\begin{bmatrix}
v_1& v_2
\end{bmatrix},$
where $v_1,v_2$ are vectors, then their dual basis $w_1,w_2$ are the functionals such that $w_i(v_j)=\delta_{ij}.$ Then in the matrix type, it would become
$$\begin{bmatrix}
    w_1\\
    w_2
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
v_1& v_2
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
    w_1\cdot v_1&w_1\cdot v_2\\
    w_2\cdot v_1&w_2\cdot v_2
\end{bmatrix}=I$$
so you need to find the inverse of $A$ and take its row vectors.

Comment: I don’t understand your answer. Also, your matrix operations do not make sense to me since they do not follow convention?

Comment: Here $v_1,v_2$ are column vectors and $w_1,w_2$ are row vectors and the $\cdot$ means the canonical inner product.